# calling a Javascript anonymous function right when it's declared, doesn't work, calling it later does

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

<kbd>[answered]</kbd>

I'm testing my browser's fps for an html5 game.
I have this code:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || //Chromium 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || //Webkit
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || //Mozilla Geko
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || //Opera Presto
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || //IE Trident?
    function(callback) { //Fallback function
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
    }
})();

var hits = 0;
var last = new Date().getTime();

var step = (function(){
    now = new Date().getTime();
    hits += 1;
    if( now - last >= 1000 ){
        last += 1000;
        console.log( "fps: "+ hits );
        hits = 0;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( step );
})();
```

It gives the following error on Chrome:
`Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17`
On line #27: `requestAnimationFrame( step );`

W3 says this error is: `If the type of an object is incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object.`
But I'm not actually interacting with the DOM at all, except for `window`

But if I remove the calling parentheses of the anonymous function assigned to `step` and instead just declare that function and on a new line I put:
`step();`

It works.
Why is this?
Shouldn't both work the same?

Comment: It seems to work in FireFox.  When I run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfP6G/), FireBug shows the `mozRequestAnimationFrame()` function object.  *EDIT:* looking at your code a little more, why are you passing step, inside `step`'s assignment?

Comment: I think that's essentially referencing an instance of an object inside it's constructor... What you're doing kind of looks like the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame but there step is declared more simply as a function...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` expects a function, but in your code, `step` is not a function, it is `undefined` because you don't return any value from your self-invoking function.

```
var step = (function(){
    // this code is executed immediately, 
    // the return value is assigned to `step` 
})();
```

If you remove the calling parenthesis, then `step` is indeed a function.

Please see @Martin's comment to this answer. I was referring to the fact that `step` is `undefined` *after* the function is executed, but of course it is also `undefined` when you invoke the function the first time.

Comment: +1 And even if step wasn't undefined at the point it gets called, it would still be undefined after since the immediate function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Martin: Right, I was actually referring to this issue and did not even notice that it is also `undefined` when the function is invoked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! it is so obvious now, but I didn't see it. The `DOM` error distracted me.

Answer (score 2):

I see some fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on here. For example, in your first declaration:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || //Chromium 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || //Webkit
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || //Mozilla Geko
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || //Opera Presto
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || //IE Trident?
    function(callback) { //Fallback function
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
    }
})();
```

You're creating an anonymous function, then immediately calling it and assigning the result to a variable. I don't see the point of this. The following would work equally well:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame || //Chromium 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || //Webkit
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || //Mozilla Geko
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || //Opera Presto
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || //IE Trident?
    function(callback) { //Fallback function
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
    };
```

There's no anonymous function now (well except for the little fallback function), it's just code that runs. You can apply a similar simplification to your `step()` function.

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary to use an anonymous function here. I assume the code is some variant of: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: @FelixKling: Good catch. Copy-paste programming rules!

Comment: You're right, I was a victim of copy & paste, but what you say makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Among the issues is this (corrected):

```
var step = function(){
    now = new Date().getTime();
    hits += 1;
    if( now - last >= 1000 ){
        last += 1000;
        console.log( "fps: "+ hits );
        hits = 0;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( step );
};
```

Comment: You had `step` assigned to the *result* of a function, instead of a function itself. My correction here assigns the function to `step`.

Comment: Oh right, your comment would have explained it better than the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues. You are assigning step the return value of the anonymous function. Whereas, when you remove the parentheses. You are making step a function. Since you are not returning a value in the anonymous function, `step` is `undefined`. Therefore, you will get a type error. I would remove the parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code essentially says "run this anonymous function and assign its return value to `step`". There are two basic problems with this:

1. The function doesn't return a value, so even after it runs `step` will be undefined.
2. Even if the function did return a value, you are trying to use `step` *inside* the function the first time it runs, at which point the assignment to `step` has not yet taken place.

The simplest way to fix this is what you already did, i.e., declare `step` as a function and then run it on the next line:

```
var step = function() { ... };
step();
```

Or you could use a named function expression:

```
(function step() {
   ...
   requestAnimationFrame( step );
})();
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
(function () {
    ...
    requestAnimationFrame( arguments.callee );
})();
```

Unfortunately [IE isn't that great at named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

And also unfortunately (unfortunate from my point of view, anyway) [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) is now deprecated and won't work in strict mode.