# Trying to make a random string generator with animation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a string randomiser with animation but its not working.

I use this function to call the function following a Frame rate that the browser picks:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback,  element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

Followed by this as my method to generate and display the string:

```
function create(chars,string_length){
output = [];
var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }


    output.push(randomstring);

    document.getElementById('cb').innerHTML = (output.join(''));
}


var chars =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var length = 20;

requestAnimFrame( create(chars,length) );
```

It generates a string to my div 'id' but only once - so the function working but it is not being called all the time =/

Why would this be ?

Comment: Similar problem found here with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583548/calling-a-javascript-anonymous-function-right-when-its-declared-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using requestAnimationFrame it will only run the function once. You need to modify `create()` to call requestAnimationFrame on itself again. Also, you are making another mistake: instead of passing the function `create()` to requestAnimationFrame, you're actually invoking `create(chars, length)` and then passing the result to requestAnimationFrame. Here's a version that should work:

```
function create(chars,string_length){
    output = [];
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }


    output.push(randomstring);

    document.getElementById('cb').innerHTML = (output.join(''));

    requestAnimFrame(function(){ create(chars,string_length); });
}


var chars =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var length = 20;

requestAnimFrame(function(){ create(chars,length) });
```

Comment: another hint: instead of writing `chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);` you can simply write `chars.charAt(rnum);`